# Getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}'

Tags: magento2

Im getting the following error after switching the site to production mode

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}'

Im getting the error on following file

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('Ves\BaseWidget\Helper\Data'); $widget_heading = $this->getConfig('title'); $addition_cls = $this->getConfig('addition_cls'); $stylecls = $this->getConfig('stylecls'); $button_title = $this->getConfig('button_title'); $href = $this->getConfig('href'); $href = str_replace(" ", "+", $href); $href = base64_decode($href); if($href) { $href = $this->getDataFilterHelper()->filter($href); } $icon = $this->getConfig('icon'); $size = $this->getConfig('size'); $color_button = $this->getConfig('color_button'); $el_class = $this->getConfig('el_class'); $content_html = $this->getConfig('html'); $content_html = str_replace(" ", "+", $content_html); $content_html = base64_decode($content_html); $content_html = $this->getDataFilterHelper()->filter($content_html); $custom_size = ''; switch ($size) { case 'small': $custom_size = 'btn-xs'; break; case 'medium': $custom_size = 'btn-sm'; break; case 'larger': case 'tall': $custom_size = 'btn-lg'; break; default: # code... break; } ?> <?php if ($href): ?> <div class="ves-widget widget-button block <?php echo $addition_cls; ?> <?php if (isset($stylecls)&&$stylecls) echo 'block-'.$stylecls;?>"><?php if (isset($widget_heading)&&!empty($widget_heading)): ?> <div class="block-title"><?php echo $widget_heading; ?></div><?php endif; ?> <div class="widget-inner block-content"><?php if ($button_title) { ?> <a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" class="btn <?php echo $color_button." ".$el_class." ".$size." ".$custom_size;?>" title="<?php echo $button_title;?>"<?php echo $content_html?(' '.$content_html):'';?>><i class="<?php echo $icon; ?>"></i> <?php echo $button_title; ?></a> <?php } ?></div></div><?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comment line (**# code** ) in the template file.

While minifying the phtml file in view_preprocessed , the comment line comments switch case close brace which results in error.

> Ves/BaseWidget/view/frontend/templates/widget/buttons.phtml

Line No : 36

```
<?php
$helper         = $this->helper('Ves\BaseWidget\Helper\Data');
$widget_heading = $this->getConfig('title');    
$addition_cls   = $this->getConfig('addition_cls');
$stylecls       =  $this->getConfig('stylecls');
$button_title   = $this->getConfig('button_title'); 
$href           = $this->getConfig('href');
$href = str_replace(" ", "+", $href);
$href = base64_decode($href);

if($href) {
    $href = $this->getDataFilterHelper()->filter($href);
}
$icon           = $this->getConfig('icon');
$size           = $this->getConfig('size');
$color_button   =  $this->getConfig('color_button');    
$el_class       = $this->getConfig('el_class');
//$color_button   = '';
$content_html   = $this->getConfig('html');
$content_html   = str_replace(" ", "+", $content_html);
$content_html   = base64_decode($content_html);
$content_html   = $this->getDataFilterHelper()->filter($content_html);
$custom_size    = '';
switch ($size) {
    case 'small':
        $custom_size    = 'btn-xs';
        break;
    case 'medium':
        $custom_size    = 'btn-sm';
        break;
    case 'larger':
    case 'tall':
        $custom_size    = 'btn-lg';
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
?>
<?php if ($href): ?>
    <div class="ves-widget widget-button block <?php echo $addition_cls; ?> <?php if (isset($stylecls)&&$stylecls) echo 'block-'.$stylecls;?>">
        <?php if (isset($widget_heading)&&!empty($widget_heading)): ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <?php echo $widget_heading; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="widget-inner block-content">
            <?php if ($button_title) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" class="btn <?php echo $color_button." ".$el_class." ".$size." ".$custom_size;?>" title="<?php echo $button_title;?>"<?php echo $content_html?(' '.$content_html):'';?>>
                <i class="<?php echo $icon; ?>"></i>
                <?php echo $button_title; ?>
            </a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('Ves\BaseWidget\Helper\Data');
$widget_heading = $this->getConfig('title');
$addition_cls = $this->getConfig('addition_cls');
$stylecls = $this->getConfig('stylecls');
$button_title = $this->getConfig('button_title');
$href = $this->getConfig('href');
$href = str_replace(" ", "+", $href);
$href = base64_decode($href);
if($href) {
    $href = $this->getDataFilterHelper()->filter($href);
}
$icon = $this->getConfig('icon');
$size = $this->getConfig('size');
$color_button = $this->getConfig('color_button');
$el_class = $this->getConfig('el_class');
$content_html = $this->getConfig('html');
$content_html = str_replace(" ", "+", $content_html);
$content_html = base64_decode($content_html);
$content_html = $this->getDataFilterHelper()->filter($content_html);
$custom_size = '';
switch ($size) {
case 'small': $custom_size = 'btn-xs'; break;
case 'medium': $custom_size = 'btn-sm'; break;
case 'larger':
case 'tall': $custom_size = 'btn-lg'; break;
default: # code...
 break;
}
?>
<?php if ($href): ?>
    <div class="ves-widget widget-button block <?php echo $addition_cls; ?>
        <?php if (isset($stylecls)&&$stylecls) echo 'block-'.$stylecls;?>">
        <?php if (isset($widget_heading)&&!empty($widget_heading)): ?>
            <div class="block-title"><?php echo $widget_heading; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="widget-inner block-content">
            <?php if ($button_title) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $href; ?>" class="btn <?php echo $color_button." ".$el_class." ".$size." ".$custom_size;?>" title="<?php echo $button_title;?>"<?php echo $content_html?(' '.$content_html):'';?>>
                    <i class="<?php echo $icon; ?>"></i>
                    <?php echo $button_title; ?>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```